# What are different between Code 1 and Code 2 in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The code 1 is from a sample project, and I modify some code and change it to code 2, and the code 2 can also run correctly.

What are different between Code 1 and Code 2 in Kotlin? Thanks!

**Code 1**

```
data class ForecastList(val id: Long, val city: String, val country: String, val dailyForecast: List<Forecast>) {

    val size: Int
        get() = dailyForecast.size

    operator fun get(position: Int) = dailyForecast[position]
}
```

**Code 2**

```
data class ForecastList(val id: Long, val city: String, val country: String, val dailyForecast: List<Forecast>) {

    val size: Int = dailyForecast.size

    operator fun get(position: Int) = dailyForecast[position]
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the syntax [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first will evaluate `dailyForecast.size` at construction, store the value in a backing field, and create an accessor that returns the value of this backing field.

The second will not create a backing field, but will instead create an accessor that returns the evaluates the expression `dailyForecast.size` every time you get the `size`.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean that Code 1 will spend small system resources?

Comment: @HelloCW Which spends more resources can depend on a lot of things. For example, how expensive is it to evaluate `dailyForecast.size`, and how often do you look at the `size` of a `ForecastList`? In most cases, `dailyForecast.size` is probably cheap to evaluate, so the efficiency difference is negligible -- go with the clearer code (#2). If `dailyForecast.size` is expensive, then use #1 if most of the time `ForecastList.size` is never called, #2 if `ForecastList.size` is usually called multiple times. (If it's usually called  once, efficiency is about the same.)

Comment: @HelloCW Sometimes one is chosen over the other not because of efficiency but because of the desired semantics. For example, if the value of  `dailyForecast.size` can change over time, and you want `ForecastList.size` to always tell you the current value, then you need to go with #1.